# ReactJS causing unnecessary re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am facing an issue with ReactJS where unnecessary re-renders are happening in my application. I have a sidebar open state that I manage in the Header component. I pass the set function to open/close the sidebar to the Header, and the state itself to the Sidebar component.

However, the `useEffect` inside the  component is re-rendering every time, even when the sidebar state is not changing.

!! Also on my every page, it's happening whenever I opened and closed

```
function App() {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(true);

  const handleSidebarOpen = () => {
    setSidebarOpen(!sidebarOpen);
  }

  {isLogin && <Header openSidebar={handleSidebarOpen} />}
    <Box display="flex">
      <SidebarDrawerExample sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen} />
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/now-playing" element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <MovieList category="now-playing" /> 
              </ProtectedRoute>
            } />
```

**MovieList.tsx**

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('category', category);
}, []);
```

Comment: I suspect the rerender is caused by something you havn't included in your question. Are there any parent components above `App`? Is `sidebarOpen` the only state in `App`? Does `App` call any custom hooks?

Comment: ````
const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(true);
const [isLogin, setLogin] = useState(false);
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();
````

Here is my state in app.  

There is nothing above app.

Comment: `useNavigate` and `useLocation` will both cause a rerender if the browser's location changes. Are you changing the url (eg, by calling `navigate` or by clicking a `<Link>` component)?

Comment: No, it's not changing or going somewhere. I'm just opening sidebar and closing.

Comment: `I'm just opening sidebar and closing` Oh... I think i'm confused then. You said "the useEffect inside the component is re-rendering every time, even when the sidebar state is not changing.", so i assumed the rerender was happening when you were **not** opening/closing the sidebar. If you're opening/closing it, then you must be setting `sidebarOpen`. If you set state, you cause a rerender.

Comment: In short, every time the sidebar is opened or closed, the useEffect within the components inside the app is triggering, despite having an empty dependency array

  <MovieList ....  => movieList.jsx

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchItems= async () => {

        fetchItems();
    }, [category, page]);
 
It's keep fetching when ı opened or closed

Comment: Gotcha, sorry for going down the wrong path there. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the handleSidebarOpen function is created inside the App component, it can cause unnecessary re-renders of the Header component when App re-renders. To optimize this, you can use the useCallback hook to memoize the handleSidebarOpen function.

Try this code:-

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(true);

  const handleSidebarOpen = useCallback(() => {
    setSidebarOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLogin && <Header openSidebar={handleSidebarOpen} />}
      <Box display="flex">
        <SidebarDrawerExample sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen} />
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/now-playing" element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <MovieList category="now-playing" />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            } />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}

const Header = ({ openSidebar }) => {
};

const SidebarDrawerExample = ({ sidebarOpen }) => {
  // Your SidebarDrawerExample component code
};

const MovieList = ({ category }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('category', category);
  }, [category]);
};
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but still, the same useEffect works when I open and close it.

  const handleSidebarOpen = useCallback(() => {
    setSidebarOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  }, []);

Comment: then there might be another cause for the re-renders, let me check